# Raspberry Pi's GPIO registers and interrupts

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, interrupt, gpio

As I can read at page 90 http://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf Raspberry Pi's GPIOs are mapped between 0x 7E20 0000 and 0x 7E20 00B0. GPIO Pin Level Registers (GPLEVn) contains every pin's value

> The pin level registers return the actual value of the pin. The LEV{n}
>   field gives the value of the respective GPIO pin.

How does the OS get these values? Or are GPIOs mapped directly into memory using DMA? Furthermore nothing is said about the polling frequency.

Regarding interrupts I found two interesting registers: GPIO Rising Edge Detect Enable Registers (GPRENn) and GPIO Asynchronous rising Edge Detect Enable Registers (GPARENn).

> The asynchronous rising edge detect enable registers define the pins
>   for which a asynchronous rising edge transition sets a bit in the
>   event detect status registers (GPEDSn). Asynchronous means the
>   incoming signal is not sampled by the system clock. As such rising
>   edges of very short duration can be detected.

Thus it seems that synchronous edge detection is implemented by sampling a pin's value at every clock, but if you have to detect rising edges of very short duration you have do it in an asynchronous way. How I am supposed do to that? Isn't everything scheduled using the system clock?

In which part of the kernel is the GPIO sampling implemented?

Comment: are you running on linux or bare metal, and if linux are you trying to write a device driver or use the existing.  If linux why not try bare metal to understand how the hardware works without the os getting in the way?

Comment: what have you tried so far (post code) and what problems are you having with that code.

Comment: @dwelch Actually I am not talking about writing code, before doing that I want to know how that works at a very low level in linux. I need to understand Raspberry Pi limits regarding I/O interactions.

Comment: so either this is not a stackoverflow question, or you need to just read the existing code.  For performance numbers this is a broadcom part so basically you have to your own experiments, which you will probably want to get the OS out of the way so that means go bare metal.'